# A user can close a script running by killing powershell task

Tags: powershell, task, kill

How can I prevent a user from killing powershell process which ends the action of the script. and how can I restart powershell by a piece of code to resume its action?

Comment: Why are you trying to make a virus?

Answer (score 4):

If the script is being run under the users account, you can't stop them from being able to kill the process.

To get around this, you could have the script run as another user (as a service, or invoking as another user) which will launch the Powershell session under their credentials, in which case only admins will be able to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience here:

In our environment we run SCCM, we have several powershell scripts that open a verbose window to let the user know that something is running.  This script is running as SYSTEM.  The user can still close the window even if they're not a member of the administrators group.

To get around crucial scripts that can't be closed I would suggest running the script silently, so that way it runs without the user even knowing.  Or, if you indeed need a GUI, use VB.NET / C# to create a form and use the form closing event to prevent the user from closing it until you're well and ready.